# Cannot open database requested by the login the login failed for user C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, runtime-error

I have developed a C# application that is a WPF based based desktop application.

Everything is working fine on my PC, but when I install the application on client computer with .Net Framework and SQL Server with instance, I get this error while running the application:

> Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for uer 'sa'.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="conString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRES;uid=sa;password=MustD0it;Initial Catalog=SMSystem;Integrated Security=false;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I actually cannot understand what exactly the error is. Some people says enable the login for user 'sa' from SQL Server Management Studio. But I have not installed the Management Studio on client computer and I don't want to install it there because the user then can see everything that is being used in database.

Comment: which option of login method did you choose when install sql server into client computer?

Comment: `.\SQLEXPRES`? `EXPRESS` has 2 `S`s in it. Also, you shouldn't be using the `sa` account for an application. Create a `LOGIN` and respective `USER` objects with the minimal amount of needed permissions.

Comment: @VietDD Sir I have used both, SQLServer auth and Windows auth.

Comment: @Larnu Sir It is .\SQLEXPRESS with double SS, I just installed another instance with single S, the first Instance is SQLEXPRESS. And can you please share a helpful article about how to create login and respective users? because I don't have Management Studio installed on client's machine

Comment: "*And can you please share a helpful article about how to create login and respective users"* Stack Overflow isn't for resource recommendations, @MuhammadNoman .